# Implementación base de datos SQL en Android studio

Tags: sql, android-studio, base-de-datos

Quería realizar una consulta a algún conocedor sobre `bases de datos` en `Android`. Implementé una pequeña `base de datos` (32 datos en una sola fila) en `Android` como prueba para evaluar cuál es la forma más optima (en lo que respecta al tiempo de carga) para las persistencias de mi aplicación. Contrastando entre tres métodos (`bases de datos`, `internal storage` y `shared preferences`) veo que en lo que respecta al tiempo de carga de los datos la `base de datos` es mucho más lenta que los otros dos métodos. Quiero cerciorarme que eso no se debe a una implementación poco optima en mi código (anexo abajo), ya que soy principiante en la programación de `bases de datos`.

Muchas gracias.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";
    private static final String TABLE_PARAMETERS = "parameters";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        //3rd argument to be passed is CursorFactory instance
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PARAMETERS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " INTEGER);";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PARAMETERS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void addValueInt(int keyName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME , keyName); // Contact Name
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_PARAMETERS, null, values);
        //2nd argument is String containing nullColumnHack
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
}

// Save data in DB when the button is clicked
    saveDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    db.addValueInt(500);
                    db.addValueInt(250);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(500);
                    db.addValueInt(250);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(500);
                    db.addValueInt(250);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(500);
                    db.addValueInt(250);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(500);
                    db.addValueInt(250);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(500);
                    db.addValueInt(250);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(500);
                    db.addValueInt(250);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(500);
                    db.addValueInt(250);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                    db.addValueInt(700);
                }
            });

// Load DB data when a button is clicked
        loadDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              long inittime = System.currentTimeMillis();
              db.getIntData(1);
              db.getIntData(2);
              db.getIntData(3);
              db.getIntData(4);
              db.getIntData(5);
              db.getIntData(6);
              db.getIntData(7);
              db.getIntData(8);
              db.getIntData(9);
              db.getIntData(10);
              db.getIntData(11);
              db.getIntData(12);
              db.getIntData(13);
              db.getIntData(14);
              db.getIntData(15);
              db.getIntData(16);
              db.getIntData(17);
              db.getIntData(18);
              db.getIntData(19);
              db.getIntData(20);
              db.getIntData(21);
              db.getIntData(22);
              db.getIntData(23);
              db.getIntData(24);
              db.getIntData(25);
              db.getIntData(26);
              db.getIntData(27);
              db.getIntData(28);
              db.getIntData(29);
              db.getIntData(20);
              db.getIntData(31);
              db.getIntData(32);
              db.getIntData(33);
              db.getIntData(34);
              db.getIntData(35);
              db.getIntData(36);
              db.getIntData(37);
              db.getIntData(38);
              db.getIntData(39);
              db.getIntData(40);
              db.getIntData(41);
              db.getIntData(42);
              db.getIntData(43);
              db.getIntData(44);
              db.getIntData(45);
              db.getIntData(46);
              db.getIntData(47);
              db.getIntData(48);
              db.getIntData(49);
              db.getIntData(50);
              db.getIntData(51);
              db.getIntData(52);
              long finaltime = System.currentTimeMillis();
              long ttime = finaltime-inittime;
              System.out.println("Total time data base storage: "+ ttime);
            }
        });


}
```

Comment: creo que tu código es bastante ineficiente.. Por qué no insertas o recuperas todos los datos a la vez? ten en cuenta que por cada vez que insertas o lees de la base de datos estás abriendo y cerrando una conexión.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte @DanielGS,  la inserción y recuperación de todos los datos a la vez se haría por medio de un bucle? un ciclo for tal vez?

Comment: Es cierto lo que comenta Daniel, la obtención de datos se realiza creando un Cursor con los datos obtenidos mediante la consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el caso que expones no debe ser significativo el tiempo para obtener los datos, incluso aún más si únicamente tienes un registro y varios campos, para obtener los datos debes realizar la consulta y almacenar los datos en un `Cursor`, posteriormente obtener los datos del `cursor`, manipular los datos almacenados en el `cursor` tiene un "performance" aceptable.

En el caso de tu pregunta es una forma incorrecta de leer la información almacenada, debería ser:

```
  String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PARAMETERS ;
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                System.out.println(cursor.getInt(0));
                System.out.println(cursor.getInt(1));  
                System.out.println(cursor.getInt(2));
                System.out.println(cursor.getInt(3));
                System.out.println(cursor.getInt(4));
                System.out.println(cursor.getInt(5));
                ...
                ...
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
```

**En el caso de usar `Preferencias` en lugar de una base de datos, esto es practico si los datos que deseas manejar son "pocos" y no tiene relaciones entre sí.**

Si los campos únicamente van a obtener un valor puedes usar `preferencias`, de lo contrario la opción es una base de datos, en el caso de usar una `preferencia` imagina guardar varios valores de un solo campo en preferencias, ahora imagina el lió que serían varios campos con más de un valor...

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys, tu respuesta me ha sacado de dudas. La cantidad de datos que quiero guardar es de aproximadamente 50 entre booleanos, double y enteros. Los valores no tienen una relación entre sí y es un solo valor para cada campo. En ese caso según me sugieres la mejor opción sería usar preferencias ya que lo que estoy buscando es una mayor agilidad en la lectura de los datos almacenados. Probé la base de datos para evaluar todos los métodos posibles y su desempeño.                                       Gracias.